# How to print the value only which is creating exception in python?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, valueerror

```
try:
    a,b = map(int,input().split())
    print(a//b)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("invalid")
except ValueError:
    print("this value _ is not allowed for division")
```

I need to print the value here _ which is caused for exceptions as "#" or "%"

Comment: Can you please describe the problem in more detail I'm having an issue understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get something similar to the code showed below. This is possible by using regular expressions (through the `search()` function of the `re` module) to find the invalid argument that comes in the exception's (`e`) arguments (`args`).

`e.args` is a tuple that looks like the following when the `ValueError` is raised because of an invalid input entered:

```
("invalid literal for int() with base 10: '%'",)
```

Therefore, we could do something as follows:

```
import re


try:
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    print(a // b)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Can't divide by zero")
except ValueError as e:
    regex_groups = re.search('\'(.+)\'|\"(.+)\"', e.args[0]).groups()
    invalid_arg = regex_groups[0] if regex_groups[0] else regex_groups[1]
    print(f"This value: {invalid_arg} is not allowed for division")
```

**Testing:**

```
1 $
This value: $ is not allowed for division
Q 2
This value: Q is not allowed for division
% '
This value: % is not allowed for division
20 ?
This value: ? is not allowed for division
50 2
25
```